# Why Can't I import Anaconda modules to Python IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, anaconda, python-idle, anaconda3

I have installed Python and Anaconda, then i opened Powershell and typed `conda list`, which shows a long list of packages. Then i went on and added the paths to environment variables.
After that i opened Python IDLE and typed `import matplotlib` but it gives the error: No module names 'matplotlib'. Same this is happening with the rest of the modules.

Comment: How is this a powershell question?

Comment: @NekoMusume It isn't. I removed the `powershell` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda and IDLE are likely using different installations. To see if this is true, in IDLE go to `File > Path Browser`. If you don't see `Anaconda` mentioned, there's the problem.

To resolve this, if you are planning to continue using Anaconda to manage packages, you can use the steps [here](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Enaraehan/python3/getting_started_win_config.html) (under `Setting Up IDLE`) to find the IDLE installation that will hook into Anaconda properly.